# Hard drive doesn't use the GUID partition scheme when installing OS X Snow Leopard 10.6

Tags: macos, installation

I recently bought an install disk for Snow Leopard and before installation it tells me that It cannot install because my hard drive doesn't use the GUID partition scheme and I am not sure what to do when partitioning the hard drive-

I need some step by step instructions better than the ones given to me by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

It makes me wonder what was on that Mac before, since all OS X installations would need that kind of partitioning.

Note: You will need to **erase your entire hard drive**.

- During the first installation screens, you should see a *Utilities* menu button on the top bar. Click it, and select *Disk Utility*.
- Here, you can partition your drive. Click the *Partition* tab and select your partition scheme — normally, 1 partition is enough. Here, click on *Options*, and make sure that "GUID Partition Scheme" is selected.
- Finally, click the *Partition* button to apply these changes.

---

For more info, check the official Apple Support page: ["You cannot install Mac OS X on this volume..." alert in Installer](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1600)

Comment: I agree about the question of what was on it before -- if this is an Intel Mac, the boot disk should always have been GPT; if it's a PowerPC Mac, the 10.6 installer wouldn't have booted it; if it's not a Mac at all, you shouldn't be installing OS X on it.

Comment: Actually, some hard drives are delivered partitioned and even NTFS-formatted. Mostly external drives or refurbished ones.